# Do I need to use damage compensation for repairs?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, money, vehicles-transportation, torts-damages

If I get a scratch on a car door and I am compensated, do I have to repair or can I just keep the money and live with the dent or scratch?

([This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9716) may be a similar question but I am unsure so I made this one a separate question.)

Answer (score 4):

The question's "I am paid for repairs" may be misleading: I seem to recall that you're paid for the difference between the market value of the car before it was damaged and its value damaged: that the payment has nothing to do with repairs. (This differs from assault on a person, where one pays for the difference in value (as above, *nezek*), repairs (*ripuy*), lost wages (*sheves*), and pain and suffering (*boshes* and *tzaar*).) Therefore, I can't see why the owner would need to repair his car. But I have no source.

Comment: correct; the absolute requirement is "car's value before" minus "car's value afterwards"; however the Shach writes that within reason, you should pay for reasonable repairs. Regardless, property is property, and you're free to do with the money as you like.